# Type Casting Math.random?

Tags: java, random, type-conversion, parentheses

Had a look around the questions on this site and could not quite find the answer I was looking for about type casting the `Math.random()` method from double to int.
My question is, why does `Math.random` only return a 0 without parentheses whereas it returns random numbers when it is contained within the parentheses?
The first part of code returns 0:

```
int number; 
number = (int) Math.random() * 10; 
System.out.println("\nThe random number is " + number);
```

This code works however:

```
int number; 
number = (int) (Math.random() * 10); 
System.out.println("\nThe random number is " + number);
```

It should be noted I have seen a few different pieces of code on typecasting whereby some programmers seem to use both ways of casting.

Comment: There are a couple of advantages to using java.util.Random rather than Math.random. It allows a forced seed, important for testing and debug. It has a nextInt(int) method that does what you are trying to do, more directly.

Comment: I read about that on another SO question actually but I am just following through the tutorials on an Oracle Java course  in which Math.Random was used as an example. I myself personally use the method you mentioned outwith tutorials. Although I do not quite understand what forced seed is and the benefits for testing.

Comment: The seed is the parameter that tells the random number generator where to start in its sequence of numbers. If it is based on time, there can be a problem reproducing a test failure if the failure path depends on the random number. java.util.Random has a constructor that lets you specify a seed. Start it with the same seed, and you will get the same sequence of numbers from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code:

```
number = (int) Math.random() * 10;
```

first calculates this:

```
(int) Math.random()
```

Since `Math.random()` returns a number from 0 up to but not including 1, if you cast it to int, it will round down to 0. Then when you multiply 10 to 0 you get 0.

Comment: @Hovercraft So placing Math.Random in parentheses first calculates the random number before doing the type conversion? So if the random number was, say 0.5, 0.5 x 10 would give 5 then it would type cast to an int while not losing any critical decimal values through truncating?

Answer (score 1):

Math.random() returns a number from 0 to 1. You want to cast the result of (Math.random()*10) to int, not the number you get from Math.random itself.
Numbers get rounded down. Therefore, for example, 0.3, which you can get from Math.random, gets rounded to 0. Again, you want to round the result of 0.3 times 10, which is 3. The parenthesis is important.

Comment: Ah I see. So the parentheses basically tell the compiler to cast the stored result of Math.random rather than the number it generates itself? All quite new to me as I previously thought parentheses were used only for arguments or arithmetic order precedence.